# how to route subdomain to another Server

Tags: subdomain, routes

I have a www.abc.com pointing to a server. Now I want another website which should be accessible by www.test.abc.com but the data for this website is on another server. How can I route?

Answer (score 0):

This can/has to be done with DNS.  You will need to create a zone in the abc.com DNS server, called test, then in the test zone, create an A record pointing www to the other server.